# Pandas line plot suppresses half of the xticks, how to stop it?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot

I am trying to make a line plot in which every one of the elements from the index appears as an xtick.

```
import pandas as pd
ind = ['16-12', '17-01', '17-02', '17-03', '17-04',
       '17-05','17-06', '17-07', '17-08', '17-09', '17-10', '17-11']
data = [1,3,5,2,3,6,4,7,8,5,3,8]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=ind)
df.plot(kind='line',x_compat=True)
```

however the resultant plot skips every second element of the index like so:
[image]

My code to call the plot includes the (x_compat=True) parameter which the documentation for pandas suggests should stop the auto tick configuratioin but it seems to have no effect.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use ticker object on axis and then use that axis when plotting.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
ind = ['16-12', '17-01', '17-02', '17-03', '17-04',
       '17-05','17-06', '17-07', '17-08', '17-09', '17-10', '17-11']
data = [1,3,5,2,3,6,4,7,8,5,3,8]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,index=ind)

ax2 = plt.axes()
ax2.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(1))

df.plot(kind='line', ax=ax2)
```

[image]